# Why am I getting No module named 'django.utils.lru_cache' error?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am working a Django project. I have created a form and tried to use Crispy-forms to style the form. However, when I run the server  I get the following error.

```
File "D:\Django_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 131, in get_package_libraries

raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to 'crispy_forms.templatetags.crispy_forms_field': No module named 'django.utils.lru_cache'
```

This is the template where I am using crispy-forms

````java
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
        {% load crispy_forms_filters %}
        {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
        {% block content %}
            <div class="content-section">
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                        {{ form |crispy }}
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="border-top pt-3">
                    <small class="text-muted">
                        Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="#">Sign In</a>
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endblock content %}```
````

I am using Django==4.0.6
Crispy-form==1.14.0

Comment: django.utils.lru_cache was removed since django 3. last django-crispy-forms with  django.utils.lru_cache was 1.9.xx.  Are your sure about your versions of django 4 and django-crispy-forms 1.14.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative hard coding with bootstrap since I couldn't find anyway to style using crispy-forms
'''
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

'''

Comment: You should markup all of your code to make it easier to read.